# How to get instance of view controller in UIButton class which is instantiated from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to access the instance of a `viewController` from the `UIButton` class which is in the framework. Whenever the `button` gets instantiated from storyboard the `init? (coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` gets called. But I am not able to understand how to access the `viewController from it.

I have a custom init method `init(viewController: UIViewController)` in `UIButton` class, which gives me `viewController` when `button` instantiated programmatically.

eg. `let button = CustomButton(viewController: self)`

But now I want to get this `viewController` instance when `button` got init by storyboard i.e. at the time of `init? (coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` call.

Until now, I am getting `viewController` object using this,

`button.viewController = self`

But I think this is not a good practice to get things. I need an alternative way.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is not a good practice to access view controller from button, you should do that other way around

Comment: @Lu_ I know and I mentioned this. That's why I am finding an alternative way. Can you please help?

Comment: Like I have said, access button from view controller not controller from button, you will have `IBOutlet` to use

Comment: I want this view controller object to navigate screens when tapping on button. And as this button is in framework, there is no other way to push screens without view controller object.

Comment: you can use delegate, button can be in framework that does not mean you can't have any `IBOutlet` to it

Comment: Add the code of your controller where you're adding the button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this code:

```
extension UIView {
    func findViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        if let nextResponder = self.next as? UIViewController {
            return nextResponder
        } else if let nextResponder = self.next as? UIView {
            return nextResponder.findViewController()
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

But in general, you should think about why you need it and is there another way to do it. For example, you can just pass a delegate to the button which will be responsible for this navigation.

Answer (score 0):

This Property is used to getting the ParentViewController(UIViewController) of any UIView.

```
extension UIResponder {  

var viewController:UIViewController? {

    if self.next is UIViewController {
        return self.next as? UIViewController
    } else {
        guard self.next != nil else { return nil }
        return self.next?.viewController
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I am trying to get viewController in framework. I got nothing in framework using your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, with the help of my friend "Pankaj Bawane", I got this working solution.

```
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```